# Teradata - Group By consecutive dates in a date range without a common ID to group by

Tags: sum, teradata

I am trying to sum the days on the job by employee:

- When `on_job_ind = Y`
- NOT total days on job for employee, but by date groupings
- There is not any kind of `job_id` to `GROUP BY`, because that would make my life
  too easy

As you can see in the table below, my `SUM()` is summing everthing where `on_job_ind = 'Y'`.  The last column in the table below, `correct_sum` is how the days_on_job need to be totaled up by date groups.

I do not know how to "break" the summation by date groups when encountering a row where `on_job_ind = 'N'`.

I have chased my tail using `LAG` and `LEAD` to no avail.

**Is what I'm trying to do possible in SQL?**

My SQL thus far:

```
SELECT emp_nbr
       , job_start_date AS act_job_start_dt
       , job_end_dt AS act_job_end_dt
       , MIN(job_start_date) over (PARTITION BY emp_nbr, on_job_ind ORDER BY job_end_dt ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS min_job_start_dt
       , MAX(job_end_dt) over (PARTITION BY emp_nbr, on_job_ind ORDER BY job_end_dt ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS max_job_end_dt
       , on_job_ind
       , days_on_job
       , SUM(days_on_job) over (PARTITION BY emp_nbr, on_job_ind ORDER BY job_end_dt ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS total_days_on_job
  FROM emp_job_tbl a
 ORDER BY 1, 3 DESC
```

Table data:

| emp_nbr | act_job_start_dt | act_job_end_dt | min_job_start_dt | min_job_end_dt | on_job_ind | days_on_job | total_days_on_job | correct_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15968 | 2/19/2023 | 3/3/2023 | 3/2/2022 | 3/3/2023 | Y | 12 | 266 | 12 |
| 15968 | 2/15/2023 | 2/19/2023 | 3/16/2022 | 2/19/2023 | N | 0 | 0 |  |
| 15968 | 2/1/2023 | 2/15/2023 | 3/2/2022 | 2/15/2023 | Y | 14 | 254 | 28 |
| 15968 | 1/18/2023 | 2/1/2023 | 3/2/2022 | 2/1/2023 | Y | 14 | 240 |  |
| 15968 | 1/7/2023 | 1/18/2023 | 3/16/2022 | 1/18/2023 | N | 0 | 0 |  |
| 15968 | 1/2/2023 | 1/7/2023 | 3/2/2022 | 1/7/2023 | Y | 5 | 226 | 18 |
| 15968 | 12/30/2022 | 1/2/2023 | 3/2/2022 | 1/2/2023 | Y | 3 | 221 |  |
| 15968 | 12/20/2022 | 12/30/2022 | 3/2/2022 | 12/30/2022 | Y | 10 | 218 |  |
| 15968 | 12/19/2022 | 12/20/2022 | 3/16/2022 | 12/20/2022 | N | 0 | 0 |  |
| 15968 | 12/16/2022 | 12/19/2022 | 3/2/2022 | 12/19/2022 | Y | 3 | 208 | 30 |
| 15968 | 12/1/2022 | 12/16/2022 | 3/2/2022 | 12/16/2022 | Y | 15 | 205 |  |
| 15968 | 11/19/2022 | 12/1/2022 | 3/2/2022 | 12/1/2022 | Y | 12 | 190 |  |
| 15968 | 11/1/2022 | 11/19/2022 | 3/16/2022 | 11/19/2022 | N | 0 | 0 |  |
| 15968 | 10/24/2022 | 11/1/2022 | 3/16/2022 | 11/1/2022 | N | 0 | 0 |  |
| 15968 | 10/7/2022 | 10/24/2022 | 3/16/2022 | 10/24/2022 | N | 0 | 0 |  |
| 15968 | 10/2/2022 | 10/7/2022 | 3/2/2022 | 10/7/2022 | Y | 5 | 178 | 19 |
| 15968 | 9/18/2022 | 10/2/2022 | 3/2/2022 | 10/2/2022 | Y | 14 | 173 |  |
| 15968 | 9/14/2022 | 9/18/2022 | 3/16/2022 | 9/18/2022 | N | 0 | 0 |  |
| 15968 | 9/1/2022 | 9/14/2022 | 3/2/2022 | 9/14/2022 | Y | 13 | 159 | 57 |
| 15968 | 8/18/2022 | 9/1/2022 | 3/2/2022 | 9/1/2022 | Y | 14 | 146 |  |
| 15968 | 8/1/2022 | 8/18/2022 | 3/2/2022 | 8/18/2022 | Y | 17 | 132 |  |
| 15968 | 7/19/2022 | 8/1/2022 | 3/2/2022 | 8/1/2022 | Y | 13 | 115 |  |
| 15968 | 7/1/2022 | 7/19/2022 | 3/16/2022 | 7/19/2022 | N | 0 | 0 |  |
| 15968 | 6/30/2022 | 7/1/2022 | 3/16/2022 | 7/1/2022 | N | 0 | 0 |  |
| 15968 | 6/20/2022 | 6/30/2022 | 3/2/2022 | 6/30/2022 | Y | 10 | 102 | 10 |
| 15968 | 6/11/2022 | 6/20/2022 | 3/16/2022 | 6/20/2022 | N | 0 | 0 |  |
| 15968 | 6/9/2022 | 6/11/2022 | 3/16/2022 | 6/11/2022 | N | 0 | 0 |  |
| 15968 | 6/1/2022 | 6/9/2022 | 3/2/2022 | 6/9/2022 | Y | 8 | 92 | 53 |
| 15968 | 5/30/2022 | 6/1/2022 | 3/2/2022 | 6/1/2022 | Y | 2 | 84 |  |
| 15968 | 5/19/2022 | 5/30/2022 | 3/2/2022 | 5/30/2022 | Y | 11 | 82 |  |
| 15968 | 5/2/2022 | 5/19/2022 | 3/2/2022 | 5/19/2022 | Y | 17 | 71 |  |
| 15968 | 4/17/2022 | 5/2/2022 | 3/2/2022 | 5/2/2022 | Y | 15 | 54 |  |
| 15968 | 4/14/2022 | 4/17/2022 | 3/16/2022 | 4/17/2022 | N | 0 | 0 |  |
| 15968 | 3/30/2022 | 4/14/2022 | 3/2/2022 | 4/14/2022 | Y | 15 | 39 | 25 |
| 15968 | 3/20/2022 | 3/30/2022 | 3/2/2022 | 3/30/2022 | Y | 10 | 24 |  |
| 15968 | 3/16/2022 | 3/20/2022 | 3/16/2022 | 3/20/2022 | N | 0 | 0 |  |
| 15968 | 3/2/2022 | 3/16/2022 | 3/2/2022 | 3/16/2022 | Y | 14 | 14 | 14 |

Comment: What is your expected result: Combining all consecutive Y in a row (Josh's answer) or your "Table data"?

Comment: Josh's answer, but I do not get the results Josh gets using his code sample.  When I run his code in Teradata, the result I get is `MAX(GROUP_END_DT) - MIN(GROUP_START_DT)` as a single line item of 366 days, not as the individual lines he shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to this one is that you actually have to consolidate 2 of the rows based on the fact that one is ending at the same time another one is beginning.

What I do is start by flagging a row for whether or not is it a "start" of a group or not. In this case, I used a window function. (Line 14)

If for some reason you can't get this to work with Teradata, please just message me because I know I've solved this on Teradata before. I no longer have access to Teradata so I tried my best. But I have solved this exact problem on Teradata many times so I know it's possible.

Here is the code that gives the result you're looking for, using Snowflake syntax. Hopefully only minor adjustments are needed.

For more information about solving this problem, the keywords to google would be "Consolidating overlapping time ranges" or the "Gaps and Islands Problem."

```
WITH VALID_DATA AS (
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM 
    RASGO.STACKOVERFLOW_Q75700970 
  WHERE 
    ON_JOB_IND = 'Y'
), 
GROUP_STARTS AS (
  SELECT 
    EMP_NBR, 
    ACT_JOB_START_DT, 
    ACT_JOB_END_DT, 
    CASE WHEN ACT_JOB_START_DT > max(ACT_JOB_END_DT) OVER (
      PARTITION BY EMP_NBR 
      ORDER BY 
        ACT_JOB_START_DT, 
        ACT_JOB_END_DT ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED preceding 
        AND 1 preceding
    ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END GROUP_START 
  FROM 
    VALID_DATA
), 
GROUPS AS (
  SELECT 
    EMP_NBR, 
    ACT_JOB_START_DT, 
    ACT_JOB_END_DT, 
    sum(GROUP_START) OVER (
      PARTITION BY EMP_NBR 
      ORDER BY 
        ACT_JOB_START_DT, 
        ACT_JOB_END_DT
    ) grp 
  FROM 
    GROUP_STARTS
), 
CONSOLIDATED AS (
  SELECT 
    EMP_NBR, 
    min(ACT_JOB_START_DT) GROUP_START_DT, 
    max(ACT_JOB_END_DT) GROUP_END_DT 
  FROM 
    GROUPS 
  GROUP BY 
    EMP_NBR, 
    grp
) 
SELECT 
  *, 
  DATEDIFF(
    'DAY', GROUP_START_DT, GROUP_END_DT
  ) AS total_days_on_job 
FROM 
  CONSOLIDATED 
ORDER BY 
  2
```

Result:

```
+---------+----------------+--------------+-------------------+
| EMP_NBR | GROUP_START_DT | GROUP_END_DT | TOTAL_DAYS_ON_JOB |
+---------+----------------+--------------+-------------------+
|   15968 | 3/2/22         | 3/16/22      |                14 |
|   15968 | 3/20/22        | 4/14/22      |                25 |
|   15968 | 4/17/22        | 6/9/22       |                53 |
|   15968 | 6/20/22        | 6/30/22      |                10 |
|   15968 | 7/19/22        | 9/14/22      |                57 |
|   15968 | 9/18/22        | 10/7/22      |                19 |
|   15968 | 11/19/22       | 12/19/22     |                30 |
|   15968 | 12/20/22       | 1/7/23       |                18 |
|   15968 | 1/18/23        | 2/15/23      |                28 |
|   15968 | 2/19/23        | 3/3/23       |                12 |
+---------+----------------+--------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: I *thought* this was the answer, but when I run this code in Teradata, the result I get is `MAX(GROUP_END_DT) - MIN(GROUP_START_DT)` as a single line item of 366 days, not as the individual lines you show.

Comment: It's probably correct, but you need to change the cumulative group number calculation to include ROWS: `sum(GROUP_START) OVER (
      PARTITION BY EMP_NBR 
      ORDER BY 
        ACT_JOB_START_DT, 
        ACT_JOB_END_DT ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
    ) grp`. In Teradata ORDER BY without ROWS returns a *group sum* instead of Standard SQL `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`

Comment: can you change the last SELECT query to select from GROUP_STARTS, GROUPS, etc just to see where the issue is arising?

Comment: The answer belongs 99% to Josh, and the 1% to dnoeth.  The missing `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` from the `SUM()` calculation got the output I was looking for.  Thank you both!!!

Comment: Gotcha! I was using snowflake since I don't have Teradata, and I found in their docs that the SUM() OVER() with an ORDER BY will imply that clause and so it worked without me having to type it! Sorry!